# How to convert the first letter of the nth column of a csv file to uppercase?

Tags: bash, csv, sed

Column 12 in a csv file is all uppercase. Sometimes the column has 3 words but for the most part, it has 1 word.

```
"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","TWELVE","thirteen"
```

I am wanting to convert column four to only have the first letter uppercase

```
"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","Twelve","thirteen"
```

I can make the entire column to lower case:

`awk -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=","} {$12 = tolower($12); print}' "$tmp_input3" > "$tmp_input4"`

and that command gives me:

```
"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen"
```

How do I make the first letter of the 12th column to be upper case?

Comment: `toupper( substr( $12, 1, 1 ) ) substr( $12, 2 )`

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output. Include more than just the sunny day cases (e.g. include a case where the first letter isn't the first character such as `7foo bar`). See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you correct my syntax? ```awk -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=","} {$12 = toupper( substr( $12, 1, 1 ) ) substr( $12, 2 ); print}' "$tmp_input4" > "$tmp_input5"```

Comment: I guess `"$tmp_input4"` contains the file path and `"$tmp_input5"` is the new file path.

Comment: So - no fields where the first char is non-alphabetic (`10 Downing St.`)? No fields that contain commas (`"foo, bar"`)? Nothing else a script might have to specifically handle? Really **think** about your real data and post sample input/output that's representative of that - don't just throw up a bunch of sunny day single lower case words unless that truly is all you have in your input (which from your previous questions it isn't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^",]\+/\L\u&/12' file
```

This converts the twelfth string which is one or more characters long and is neither a comma or a double quotes, to lowercase except for the first character which it uppercases.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `toupper(substr($12,1,1)) substr($12, 2)`:

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=","} {$12 = toupper(substr($12,1,1)) substr($12, 2)}1' "$tmp_input3" > "$tmp_input4"
```

That is, you turn the first char to upper case with `toupper(substr($12,1,1))` and then append the rest of the chars beginning from Index 2.

See the [online `awk` demo](https://ideone.com/GtbNLq):

```
s="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,abc def ghi,end"
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$12 = toupper(substr($12,1,1)) substr($12, 2)}1' <<< "$s"
# => 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,Abc def ghi,end
```

Comment: This fails if there is only one word in the 12th column

Comment: @CuriousSam no it doesn't, Wiktor just answered before you posted the sample input/output so he didn't know that your fields are quoted.

Comment: @CuriousSam Even if there is a single letter word, it [does not fail](https://ideone.com/wl6WSJ).